# How to double only numbers in a string (which has numbers, words etc) in C?

Tags: c, string

I need to write a function called `doubleString` that receives a string and then multiplies all the numbers in the text by 2. The function should return a pointer to the beginning of the received string for easier chaining.

Example: If the input string is

"This sentence contains number 4, number 8 and number 88"

after calling the function the string should read:

"This sentence contains number 8, number 16 and number 176".

It is not allowed to use the functions from the `string.h`, `stdlib.h` libraries, as well as the `sprintf` and `sscanf` functions from the `stdio.h` library. It is not allowed to create helper strings in a function or globally.

I have written code, but it only works when a string with no words is entered, just numbers. While trying I have also had issues such as the program not working for numbers above 445, or getting different output each time. This is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void inputString(char array[], int size) {
    char character = getchar();
    if (character == '\n') character = getchar();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < size - 1 && character != '\n') {
        array[i] = character;
        i++;
        character = getchar();
    }
    array[i] = '\0';
}

char *doubleString(char *text) {
    int carry = 0;
    int length = 0;

    while (text[length] != '\0') {
        length++;
    }

    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (text[i] >= '0' && text[i] <= '9') {
            int digit = ((int)text[i]) * 2 + carry;
            carry = digit / 10;
            text[i] = (digit % 10) + '0';
        }
    }

    while (carry > 0) {
        for (int i = length; i > 0; i--) {
            text[i] = text[i - 1];
        }

        text[0] = (carry % 10) + '0';

        carry /= 10;
        length++;
    }

    return text;
}

int main() {
    char text[1000];
    int size = sizeof(text);
    printf("Enter text: ");
    inputString(text, size);

    char *result = doubleString(text);

    printf("'%s'", result);

    return 0;
}
```

The program doesn't work for this case:

Input:

```
'U ovoj recenici se nalazi broj 4, broj 8 i broj 88'
```

Expected output:

```
'U ovoj recenici se nalazi broj 8, broj 16 i broj 176'
```

My output:

```
'U ovoj recenici se nalazi broj 9, broj 7 i broj 76'
```

But works for this case:

Input:

```
"1 i 1 jesu 2"
```

Expected output:

```
'2 i 2 jesu 4'
```

My output:

```
'2 i 2 jesu 4'
```

Comment: `(int)text[i]` does not do what you think it does. Use `text[i] - '0'` instead.

Comment: what about `"hello99world"` ?

Comment: @gulpr the output should be hello198world.

Comment: What is a 'helper string' (that can't be created)?

Comment: @Persixty I meant that no other strings can be declared other than the original input one.

Comment: OK. So I assume the solution is permitted to assume there is enough space to perform the process in-place. Obviously lots of numbers get longer when doubled (5-9, 50-99, etc.).

Comment: @Persixty Yes..

Comment: I suggest using a shorter string for testing, like `a8b9` or `3 4 5 6 7`. [Use a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/509868).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[@anatolyg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77721779/2410359) (currently deleted) well identifies that code cannot *simply* replace in-place as substrings like `"99"` are to be replaced with a longer `"198"`.

After finding the string end, make 2 passes down the string.  The first simply determines the additional offset needed and the 2nd, using like code, starts at the new end and does the copy.

Code does not use `int` indexing as strings may be longer than `INT_MAX`.

`((int)text[i]) * 2 + carry` is amiss.
Better as `(text[i] - '0') * 2 + carry;` [@Weijun Zhou](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77721712/how-to-double-only-numbers-in-a-string-which-has-numbers-words-etc-in-c/77722026#comment137020132_77721712)
.

OP's `while (carry > 0) {` only well handles a leading numeric sub-string.  There may be many.

To remove unneeded leading zeros, the loop that finds the end of the string also shortens the string when unneeded leading zeroes are found.

```
/*
 * Copy in-place string 'src' to `src` with each sub-string of digits doubled in value.
 */
char* double_str(char *src);

#define IS_DIGIT(ch) ((ch) >= '0' && (ch) <= '9')

char* double_str(char *src) {
  char *s0 = src;
  char *d0 = src;

  // Remove unneeded leading zeroes and find end.
  int is_numeric = 0;
  while (*s0) {
    while (!is_numeric && s0[0] == '0' && IS_DIGIT(s0[1])) {
      s0++;
    }
    is_numeric = IS_DIGIT(*s0);
    *d0++ = *s0++;
  }
  *d0 = '\0';

  char *end = d0;
  char *new_end = end;

  // Make 2 passes.
  // 1st to find the new end of the string.
  // 2nd to copy the string.
  for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    int carry = 0;
    char *s = end;
    char *d = new_end;
    if (i > 0) {
      *d = '\0';
    }
    while (s > src) {
      s--;
      if (IS_DIGIT(*s)) {
        int new_digit = (*s - '0')*2 + carry;
        if (i > 0) {
          d--;
          *d = (char)(new_digit % 10 + '0');
        }
        carry = new_digit/10;
        // Do we have a non-zero carry and the prior character is not a digit?
        if (carry && (s == src || !IS_DIGIT(s[-1]))) {
          if (i > 0) {
            d--;
            *d = '1';
          }
          new_end++;
        }
      } else {
        if (i > 0) {
          d--;
          *d = *s;
        }
        carry = 0;
      }
    }
  }
  return src;
}
```

Test code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char src_text[1000] = "5x2x5x9x15x99x500000000000000000000000000x";
  //printf("Enter text: ");
  //inputString(text, size);
  printf("'%s'", double_str(src_text));
  return 0;
}
```

Ouptut

```
'10x4x10x18x30x198x1000000000000000000000000000x'
```

Comment: Okey, it works well, but for the input example:  'Za broj 044 ispravno rjesenje je i 088 i 88' i get the output 'Za broj 088 ispravno rjesenje je i 176 i 176'   when i should get either  088, 0176 and 176   or   88, 176, 176.    So either without the 0 or with it, but I seem to get a mix, since 088 is with a zero but 176 is without.

Comment: @Irma Ibrović.  OK,  will review.  What output do you prefer: `088, 0176 and 176` or `88, 176, 176`?

Comment: Without 0, so 88, 176, 176.

Comment: @IrmaIbrović OK.  Best to add those test cases to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is within the doubling process: your code iterates over all digits within the string moving the carry from a sequence of digits to the next. So you should repeat the shifting of the text and reset the carry after each sequence.

```
int strlen(char *str) {
    int len = 0;
    while(str[len] != '\0')
        ++len;
    return len;
}

int isdigit(int c) {
    return c >= '0' && c <= '9';
}

char *doubleString(char *text) {
    int i, j, len, carry = 0, c;
    
    len = strlen(text);
    for(i = len-1; ; --i) {
        /* the check for the loop is moved because we want to check carry > 0 at the end of the process */
        if (i < 0 || !isdigit(text[i])) {
            while(carry > 0) {
                for(j = ++len; j > i+1; --j)
                    text[j] = text[j-1];
                text[j] = carry % 10 + '0';
                carry /= 10;
            }
            if (i < 0) break;
        }
        else {
            c = (text[i] - '0') * 2 + carry;
            carry = c / 10;
            text[i] = c % 10 + '0';
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```